# Double boot with windows locks NTFS partitions

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, hibernate

First message here. I posted this question also in SuperUser, but it probably gets also exposure here.

I'm trying to set up my laptop for double booting Linux and Windows. I have two SSD, one SATA and one NVME.m2. Both are GPT formatted

I'm following the instructions from Arch Wiki to have both OS being able to hibernate independently. I basically have an EFI partition in each drive, one with the Windows bootloader and the other with GRUB for Linux and Windows. Both system partitions (windows C: and Linux /) are on the m2 drive, although the Linux EFI partition is on the SATA drive. I think this is cool .

However, there's a shared data partition on the SATA drive that must be available for both systems. This is a NTFS partition, mounted on Linux using the NTFS-3g driver.

However, when Windows hibernate, this partition is locked. The Arch wiki recommends to mount that partition "*as an external drive in Windows and ejecting the drive in Windows before hibernating*". Sounds cool, but I have no idea how to do that. Or something even more direct, like disable the locking of a partition during the windows hibernation.

Any help is appreciated

<s>Sorry for not posting links to the documentation I'm using. I'll update this post later with more details if anyone is interested</s>

The link to Arch Linux documentation mentioned
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Disable_Fast_Startup_and_enable_hibernation

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In researching this topic, I only found workarounds, not true solutions as what you're asking for:

1. Reformat the partition as FAT32, or
2. Unmount the partition before hibernating.

If you need large file support - i.e., > 4GB - you can try using exFAT instead of FAT32.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used FAT32 in my first few dual boot laptops, and didn't like it. Settled for NTFS-3g and it was fine until the hibernate factor is included. I'm not event sure how to unmount this partition in Windows before hibernation. What I do is a batch file on my Windows desktop that reboots the PC without using hibernation or fast boot or any of those hacks. It gets the work done, but getting back to Windows feels like decades

Comment: This tutorial should help: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/158668-how-mount-unmount-drive-volume-windows.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll look into MS specific forums to see if it's possible to make PowerShell script with those steps. I could put it on my desktop and hibernate after that script. Heck, I put the hibernation within the script and remount the NTFS after it wakes up, if the script keeps running afterwards. That would be awesome. Or making Win10 execute this script automatically with it's hibernation feature. Maybe some registry modification. Let me see. Thanks!